# Is there a way to store drywall vertically on its side?

Tags: drywall, storage

I am going to have a surplus of 8 sheets of 5/8" 4x8 drywall (4 type-x, 4 QuietRock 525) until my next soundproofing job this Summer.  I have been storing 8 sheets at a time stacked flat on my upstairs guest room floor, but I don't want to store the remainder up there until Summer.  If I could store it vertically up against the wall wrapped in plastic in my garage, that'd be great.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to share your project with the class as a blog post?  A couple before and after pictures, some links to the various questions you've asked along the way, and some things you've learned throughout the project would make a great post.

Comment: It's going to be a few more months before it's done, but I have lots of pictures and experience to share.  Next on my list is apply drywall to the ceiling. After that, fix up the floor with probably MLV, Green Glue, and Homasote.  Finally, soundproof the doors.  If it all proves effective, I'll post a very long and well-written account of my experiences.

Comment: You could always make it an ongoing series, instead of a single huge post.  You could break it down in to sections (demo, preparation/planning, installation, finish, etc...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could build a drywall storage rack.

- Start by building 2 or 3 triangular frames out of scrap 2x4s.

[image]

- Space them out to the desired length.

[image]

- To prevent sheets from sagging between supports, lay a sheet of plywood on the rack before placing drywall on it.

[image]

A rack like this may be overkill for a short term storage solution, but could come in handy if you find yourself storing drywall for extended periods. It's nice because you can store the drywall in less space, it keeps the drywall off the ground/floor, and it prevents the drywall from warping.

Comment: I ended up going sorta this route.  I didn't have spare 2x4s, but I did have plywood.  I leaned them up against the wall at an angle and then leaned the drywall on those.  QuietRock 525 has heavy backer board on the back, so I put that up first.  After four sheets of that, my remaining sheets of type-x were well supported.  Thanks for your answer, too, BMitch.  I upvoted it.

Answer (score 10):

It's stored on it's side (beveled edge up/down) all the time on job sites. Just make sure to protect bottom edge and keep it off the ground if there's a moisture risk. The best solution is to get 3 or 4 of the blocks of drywall that they have when delivering it (allows them to get the forklifts under a stack) and use those to keep it off the ground. In addition to avoiding moisture, the important part is to avoid tearing the paper and placing too much stress in one place or over too long of a span.

Comment: Make sure you strap it to the wall or something.  I know 1/2" will bow if it's just leaned against a wall for months.

Comment: I have some drywall waste that I can use to keep it off the ground.  It's 5/8" and is going to be there for several months (potentially Summer as I said previously), so it will definitely be okay so long as it's kept flat?  Also, what about the paper tearing?  Some of the drywall sheets' faces got scuffed during shipping and the outer layer of paper is torn away leaving the brown layer beneath (no drywall is showing).

Comment: @oscilatingcretin, the paper is half the strength of the drywall (plaster doesn't compress, but it offers no resistance to being pulled apart), so do your best to avoid damage.